# python3 sort a list of dictionaries by an attribute of the dict values

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries stored in `part_results` like this:

```
[{'Pad': FAILED! 69% Pad in BF1, serf = 12.06 ≤ 17.4.}, 
 {'Pipe': FAILED! 196% Pipe in BF1, pmax = 205.38 ≤ f_pipe_ = 104.67 MPa.},
 {'Foot plate': FAILED! 89% Foot plate in BF1, serf = 34.90 ≤ 39.1.}]
```

The values of the dicts are nicely printed objects (always a single object) that have an attribute 'utilisation'; these are the percent values in the print.

I'd like to have the list ordered by the utilisation values, but I have a hard time to find out how to access the value of each dict in a pythonic way.

The output would be

```
[{'Pipe': FAILED! 196% Pipe in BF1, pmax = 205.38 ≤ f_pipe_ = 104.67 MPa.},
 {'Foot plate': FAILED! 89% Foot plate in BF1, serf = 34.90 ≤ 39.1.},
 {'Pad': FAILED! 69% Pad in BF1, serf = 12.06 ≤ 17.4.}]
```

My first attempt was something like

```
sorted(part_results, key=lambda x: part_results)
```

which is clearly not what I want: it will sort by the dict keys. I know, no sorting key is needed to achieve this, but the lambda is necessary to access the values of the dicts within the loop - how do I do that?

Comment: That's not a valid Python `dict` to begin with. Can you post the actual dictionary structure you want to sort, `utilisation` value included?

Comment: @zwer He probably just `print`ed it and their objects implement `__repr__` in that way... Yeah, @jake77  `__repr__` should **not** pretty print anything. It should be `__str__` to do that...

Comment: ... but its enough to illustrate the point, the object has about twenty attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that there is always a single key-value pair in each `dict`, you can try:

```
sorted(part_results, key=lambda d: list(d.values())[0].utilisation)
```

This sorts the list of dicts by the `utilisation` attribute of their respective first (and only) value.

Comment: `part_results[x]` is a dict with the key being a string, the value a single custom object

Comment: It almost does; in python 3 .values() does not return a list by a dict view so `sorted(part_results, key=lambda d: list(d.values())[0].utilisation)`is OK